# Unit testing handlebar partials

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, jestjs

I want to unit test my application using Jest which is using Handlebar as a templating engine.

I am able to unit test the Handlebar helpers but not able to test the Handlebar partials.

When I try to import the partials in the spec.js, I am getting an error:

> Unexpected character '#' (1:2)

Below is the partial.handlerbars file

```
{{#with (resource 'some_selector') }}
 <img alt="{{altText}}" src="{{image-url}}" />
{{/with}}
```

Below is the partial.spec.js

```
import partial from './partial.handlebars';
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
describe('partial suite', ()=> {
  Handlebars.registerPartial('partial', partial);
  it('should always be true', ()=> {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  })  
})
```

Below is the error:

```
 D:/projects/src/components/partials/partial.handlebars: Unexpected character '#' (1:2)
  > 1 | {{#with (resource 'some_selector') }}
      |   ^
```